# Is there a more succinct way to to write this reducer function that changes an item in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I notice that a lot of my reducers follow a common pattern, they find an item in an array by a unique id and change its properties. Right now the pattern I use looks like this:

```
case ActionTypes.CHANGE_DOCUMENT: {
  const documents = cloneArray(state.documents);

  const documentIndex = documents.findIndex(o => o.id === action.id);
  const document = documents.find(o => o.id === action.id);

  documents[documentIndex] = {
    ...document,
    ...action.documentExtension
  }

  return {
    ...state,
    documents
  }      
}
```

Is this a good pattern for making changes to a unique element in an array? To me it looks alright but I'm wondering if others have found a more elegant/concise solution for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking @JohnRuddell's answer and iterating it further:

```
case ActionTypes.CHANGE_DOCUMENT: {
  const documents = state.documents.map((document) => ({
    ...document,
    ...(document.id === action.id ? action.documentExtension : {}),
  }));

  return {
    ...state,
    documents,
  };
}
```

**Updated answer** based on @markerikson 's feedback and link to [Redux documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html#updating-an-item-in-an-array).

```
case ActionTypes.CHANGE_DOCUMENT: {
  const documents = state.documents.map((document) => {
    return (document.id !== action.id) ? document : {
        ...document,
        ...action.documentExtension,
    };
  });

  return {
    ...state,
    documents,
  };
}
```

Comment: Wow nice! Thanks

Comment: question. if you return a new object for every document in the array wouldn't that cause more processing / a performance hit in terms of the react render function? (because it will re render every document)

Comment: My understanding is that React looks for changes in object references to determine whether a re-render is required. It then re-renders the virtual DOM using the new data (it'd re-render the entire virtual DOM for a single change). It then diffs the virtual and real DOM, and updates only the changed elements of the real DOM as required.

Comment: But I've only been using React for about a month, so I may be wrong.

Comment: Yeah, this example is going to be bad for performance.  The `documents.map()` call should **not** spread every item.  The better approach is to return unwanted items as-is, and replace the one item that should be updated.  See [Redux Docs: Immutable Update Patterns#Updating an Item in an Array](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html#updating-an-item-in-an-array) for an example of how to do this correctly.

Comment: yea, so when it looks for a change in object references and every object has a new reference its going to trigger the re render of each one. even if its virtual dom its still more processing and potentially a performance hit. I didn't downvote though :) just pointing it out :D

Answer (score 2):

yes you can clean up the code by just doing one map over the documents, update the one you want to update while doing one pass over the documents array. This cuts the time complexity in half

```
const documents = state.documents.map( (document, index) => {
    if (document.id === action.id) {
        return {
            ...document,
            ...action.documentExtension
        }
    } else {
        return document
    }
});
```

or a little more inline

```
const documents = state.documents.map( (document, index) => document.id === action.id ? {...document, ...action.documentExtension} : document);
```

Comment: This line isn't required: `let documents = [].concat(state.documents);`, because `map` returns a new array anyway.

Comment: @fubar true true

Comment: I've iterated your answer yet further. If you agree with the changes, I'd be happy to delete my answer and for you to update yours. Otherwise I will leave it as another alternative for OP. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43334616/4604701

Comment: @fubar no problem :) you can keep yours! its always good to have variety